# A "uniform" distribution on the set of bijections on the positive integers

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $S$ be the collection of increasing sequences of positive integers $\mathbf{N}$. Then, it is well known that there exists a bijection between $S$ and $(0,1]$, where an increasing sequence $(a_n)$ is identified with a real 
$$
\sum_{i\ge 1}d_i 2^{-i} \in (0,1]
$$
with $d_i \in \{0,1\}$ for all $i$, and infinitely many $1$ (in particular, $d_i=1$ if and only if $i=a_n$ for some $n$). In this way, considering the (restriction of the) Lebesgue's measure on $(0,1]$, we can assign a kind of "uniform" distribution on $S$.

Now, let us consider the collection $P$ of bijections $\pi: \mathbf{N} \to \mathbf{N}$. Is it possible to construct a similar "uniform" distribution on $P$?